# How to select a column in the next row?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

How can I select QuestionId in the next row via stored procedure?

(Client side: a question(QuestionId:3) will be shown on screen. When next button is clicked, next question(QuestionId:7) will be shown).

**Note that;** 
QuestionId has to be changed incrementally and continuously according to RowId after every execution(like 1-3-7-8...). Also any question can be deleted so it is important to keep the order.

```
+-------+------------+--------------+
| RowId | QuestionId | QuestionText |
+-------+------------+--------------+
| 1     | 1          | aaaa         |
| 2     | 3          | bbbb         |
| 3     | 7          | cccc         |
| 4     | 8          | dddd         |
| 5     | 13         | eeee         |
| 6     | 17         | ffff         |
| 7     | 24         | gggg         |
| 8     | 30         | hhhh         |
+-------+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetNextQuestion

@QuestionID int

AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT TOP 1 RowId, QuestionId, QuestionText
    FROM Questions
    WHERE QuestionID > @QuestionID
    ORDER BY QuestionID

GO
```

Clicking the "Next" button should pass the current question ID to the stored procedure.

Comment: Without an `order by` clause all bets are off.

Comment: @user92546 - Derp, you're absolutely right, added.  Time to get more coffee.